# Object has no attribute

Tags: python

При подключении клиента вылетает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class  serv_sock:

def __init__(self):
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.bind(('', 9090))
    self.sock.listen(5)
    self.prognoz = pogoda()

def connect(self):
    print('Жду соедения...\n')
    self.conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
    print('Соедение с клиентом, адрес ', addr)
    self.pogoda_client()

def getData(self):
    while True:
        data = self.conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
    return data

def sendData(text, self):
    self.conn.send(text)

def closeSock():
    self.sendData('exit')
    self.conn.close()
    connect()

def pogoda_client(self):
    while True:
        self.sendData('Город: ')
        name_city = self.getData()
        self.prognoz.geIdCity(name_city)
        if self.prognoz.error != ' ':
            self.sendData('Город не найден\n')
            continue
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас опечатка. Вместо

```
def sendData(text, self):
```

должно быть

```
def sendData(self, text):
```

Первым параметром методы в Python принимают объект, у которого вызвали метод. Вызов `foo.sendData(bar)` на самом деле превращается в `sendData(foo, bar)`.

У вас получалось, что вызов `self.sendData("foo")` превращался в `sendData(self, "foo")`, а дальше из-за неверного порядка аргументов получалось, что `text` связан с объектом `serv_sock`, а `self` связан со строчкой, которую вы пробуете передать. При попытке обратиться к `self.conn` возникала ошибка: у строчки отсутствует свойство `conn`.